# Copy the contents of a DataGridView in to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, office-interop

I found some [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/ExportDatagridviewToExcel.aspx) of how to create a excel file from a data grid view, however those just create the file. What I would like to do is have excel open, with a unsaved worksheet, and have the content of the data grid view (including header names) pasted in to the worksheet after pressing a "Export to Excel" button.

Basically I want to automate what happens when you do a copy and paste from a data grid view in to excel. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial, http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/LA/Import-Export-DataGrid-XLS-XLSX-CSV-HTML-.NET.htm.  It shows how to generate an excel document from the datagrid export.  You can then open the document which will open it in excel.  I'm not entirely sure of a way to paste it into the currently open excel document but this should get you close.